# How to concatenate all values from the same row in a column sql?

Tags: sql, concatenation

Please consider the following records in a table:

```
ID    Name    City
------------------
1    SAM      New York
2    Mike     Orlando
3    Jane     Boston
```

I would like to get the following result from a query:

```
1,SAM,New York
2,Mike,Orlando
3,Jane,Boston
```

I would like to use other solution than the classical concatenation with '+' because there are a lot of columns and I need to apply this to multiple tables.

Could you please give me any ideas?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds less like a query problem and more like a rendering issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(`id`, ' ', `name`, ' ', `city`) as `row` FROM `table`
```

Use the [CONCAT](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm) function

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DBMS, You could set your column separator to the comma and your output format to unaligned.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine following scenario:

1. Create procedure or function
2. Pass table name as parameter
3. In the function select columns from table, iterate over them and create sql you need. I mean it will be generated sql like `SELECT column1||','||column2,...FROM you_table`
4. Execute it using EXECITE IMMEDIATE (if it is Oracle), depends on database
5. Use results